# ASA 5505 :: Escape Key

Tags: cisco-asa

I knew this at one point, and can longer find the reference on Google.

While a small annoyance, I would like to quickly jump out of a screen (say, "sh ru", or the more lengthy version, "show running-config") without space bar'ing through to the end.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<kbd>q</kbd>

Comment: ha, the simple things ;-)